# How to collapse similar looking columns into one and assign a name to it in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a `csv` which looks like below

```
AB22,AD34,GQ22,BQ77a1,BQ77a2,BQ77a3,CA33,LA21,MO22c1,MO22c4
"ab,vd","va,ca","aa","ba,po,la","ma,na,qa","la,oo,aa","ca","na,la","re,te","ka,lo"
"vb,zr","ra,oa","na","oa,yo,sa","xa,ia,ga","lk,po,za","ja","ka,la","rv,gh","xa,jk"
```

The above `csv` is just a shorter version of the bigger `csv` I have. It has more rows and more columns. But this example is good enough for my question.

Now I have a list of column names which looks like this

```
columns = ["BQ77", "MO22"]
```

Now I need to look up the columns in the `csv` which looks like each of column names I have in the list and collapse such columns into one where I make the values comma separated.

For example for the column `BQ77`, the columns that look like it in the `csv` are `BQ77a1,BQ77a2,BQ77a3` and for the column `MO22`, the columns in the `csv` are `MO22c1,MO22c4`

Now such columns need to be collapsed and the values need to joined together (comma separated) and the column name should be the column from the `columns` list.

So my `csv` should look like this

```
AB22,AD34,GQ22,BQ77,CA33,LA21,MO22
"ab,vd","va,ca","aa","ba,po,la,ma,na,qa,la,oo,aa","ca","na,la","re,te,ka,lo"
"vb,zr","ra,oa","na","oa,yo,sa,xa,ia,ga,lk,po,za","ja","ka,la","rv,gh,xa,jk"
```

I created a mapping of columns given in the list with the columns in the `csv` which match them. So this is what I did

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ["BQ77", "MO22"]
df = pd.read_excel(io="/Users/souvikray/Downloads/test.xlsx", sheet_name="A1") // file originally is an excel file
headers = df.columns.tolist()
col_map = {}
for column1 in columns:
    for column2 in headers:
        if column1 in column2:
            if col_map.get(column1):
                col_map[column1].append(column2)
            else:
                col_map[column1] = [column2]
```

So I get a mapping

```
col_map = {"BQ77": ["BQ77a1", "BQ77a2", "BQ77a3"], "MO22": ["MO22c1","MO22c4"]}
```

Now I am not sure how can I use this information to do a collapse of similar looking columns. I also looked up online and found this question [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas) but here the columns are continuous but in my case, the required columns occur at certain places

Is there any way this can be done?

**Note:** Since I didn't post the entire csv, so one thing to keep in mind is the column values may have int and float too.

Comment: whats your ideal output? can you test `df.filter(regex='|'.join(columns)).melt()`

Comment: @Datanovice ok sure. I have already posted my ideal output. Look for`So my csv should look like this` .I will test if your suggestion works

Comment: @Datanovice doesn't; seem to work. I do not see the columns getting collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,`df` is your main dataframe

```
A=[["ab,vd","va,ca","aa","ba,po,la","ma,na,qa","la,oo,aa","ca","na,la","re,te","ka,lo"],
   ["vb,zr","ra,oa","na","oa,yo,sa","xa,ia,ga","lk,po,za","ja","ka,la","rv,gh","xa,jk"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(A ,columns = ["AB22","AD34","GQ22","BQ77a1","BQ77a2","BQ77a3","CA33","LA21","MO22c1","MO22c4"])   
columns = ["BQ77", "MO22"]
for c in columns:
    cc = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith(c)]
    df[c] = df[cc].apply(','.join, axis=1)
    df=df.drop(columns=cc,axis=1)
```

output

```
AB22   AD34 GQ22 CA33   LA21                        BQ77         MO22
0  ab,vd  va,ca   aa   ca  na,la  ba,po,la,ma,na,qa,la,oo,aa  re,te,ka,lo
1  vb,zr  ra,oa   na   ja  ka,la  oa,yo,sa,xa,ia,ga,lk,po,za  rv,gh,xa,jk
```

Comment: hi, your solution maybe correct .But because I didn't post the entire csv, so you are not aware of this. Actually the column values might have `float` and `int` too. So it throws error as `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected string, float found', u'occurred at index 0')`. Can there be a check where the `join` happens only for string values. Sorry I didn't' make this obvious.

Comment: @SouvikRay use `df[cc].astype(str).apply(','.join, axis=1)`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thanks. I moved one step further. But now it throws a `UnicodeEncodeError`. Guess I have to do something similar like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484350/5550284

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I figured it out. On using `as type('unicode')` it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: @SouvikRay Good for you.

Comment: thank you @ShubhamSharma  for helping while i am off... Souvik happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, using `join` `stack` and `filter`

```
s = df.filter(regex='|'.join(columns)).stack().reset_index()

df1 = df.join(
    s.groupby([s["level_0"], s["level_1"].str[:2]])[0].agg(",".join).unstack(1)
).drop(s["level_1"].unique(), axis=1).rename(columns={'BQ' : 'BQ77', 'MO' : 'MO22' })

print(df1)

    AB22   AD34 GQ22 CA33   LA21                        BQ77         MO22
0  ab,vd  va,ca   aa   ca  na,la  ba,po,la,ma,na,qa,la,oo,aa  re,te,ka,lo
1  vb,zr  ra,oa   na   ja  ka,la  oa,yo,sa,xa,ia,ga,lk,po,za  rv,gh,xa,jk
```

Comment: @Datanvoice can this code be modified to handle `UnicodeEncodeError` ?